# Show git branch name of a selected folder in mac menu bar

Tags: osx, git, menu

I want to see the current branch in git of a preselected folder in my Mac's menu bar. Is there an app that shows.

[image: Mac menu bar]

I have tried to install [headsondisplay](http://www.headsondisplay.com) but the app store says the item is not available in Australia or the US store for some reason.